# Can i get constraints of uibutton created through storyboard?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

I want all available constraints of uibutton created through storyboard. Actually i want to modify particular constraint within uitableviewcell.

Comment: If you want to manipulate a particular constraint, why not just ctrl-drag from that constraint to your @IBOutlet for the constraint?

Comment: can't drag directly. uibutton is within uitableviewcell.

Comment: You have to make a custom UITableViewCell subclass and add the @IBOutlet to that class.  Then you can set the cell's custom class and ctrl-drag from the constraint to the cell in the navigator on the left of the storyboard

Comment: ok i have created custom cell class. added iboutlet to that cell class. connected uibutton's constraint with drag. imported that class to uiview class file where tableview implemented. 
iboutlet is "@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *height;"
but how to get that "height" within tableviewcell?

Comment: Thanks man. its working now. forgot to use custom cell class on cell identifier within cellForRowAtIndexPath :)